# Is there a way to run MS flow without seeing the sidebar menu for run-only users?

Tags: power-automate

I am new with MS flow, we created a support request form where end-users can create and submit support requests on their own instead of our team manually creating them after we receive their requests through email.

Is there a way that when users run the flow, they would only see the "flow" itself and not with a sidebar menu? I guess my goal is to make it look like a web page.

[image: how to get ride of that sidebar for run-only users]

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to create a form in MS Forms or SharePoint/InfoPath. There's no way to hide the sidebar menu from users who *log in to Microsoft Flow/Power Automate*... they're logging in as normal Flow users, so it's only natural that they see the sidebar menu.

See https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/building-scratch-forms-responses/ for more info on this.